# Date by adding time interval

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a project which downloads data On click of a button.The user should be allowed to download the next data after 24 hours. How can  a event handler be used to execute the above problem

suppose i download the data today, it should allow me to download next data tomorrow(24 hours)
thanks in advance.